# Monadic concatMap for Data.Vector?

Tags: haskell, vector, monads

I'm looking for something from the Data.Vector package which works like `concatMap` but works with monads. `concatMap` has type...

```
(a -> Vector b) -> Vector a -> Vector b
```

but I'm looking for something with type...

```
(Monad m) => (a -> m (Vector b)) -> Vector a -> m (Vector b)
```

... or, in particular, either one of:

```
(MonadRandom m) => ((Int, Int) -> m (Vector Int)) 
                -> Vector (Int, Int) -> m (Vector Int)

(MonadRandom m) => (Int -> Int -> m (Vector Int))
                -> Vector (Int, Int) -> m (Vector Int)
```

The code below should give an idea of what I'm trying to do but produces the error

> Couldn't match type `VU.Vector Int` with `Int`
>   Expected type: `m (VU.Vector Int)`
>   Actual type: `m (VU.Vector (VU.Vector Int))`
>   In the expression: `return $ VU.concatMap mate mates`

```
import           Control.Monad
import           Control.Monad.Random 
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed  as VU

testReprod :: IO()
testReprod = do
  let parents = VU.fromList [1::Int,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
  children <- reproduce parents
  print children

-- concat monadic
reproduce :: (MonadRandom m) => (VU.Vector Int) -> m (VU.Vector Int)
reproduce parents = return $ VU.concatMap mate mates
    where
  half = VU.length parents `div` 2
  mates = VU.zip (VU.take half parents) (VU.drop half parents)
  mate :: (MonadRandom m) => (Int, Int) -> m (VU.Vector Int)
  mate (a, b) = do
    r1 <- getRandomR(0,5)
    r2 <- getRandomR(0,5)
    return $ VU.fromList [a+r1, b+r2]
```

While the `mate` function in the example does not actually rely on getting a tuple of values, the actual code from which the example is based on does.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are looking for (or what I'm supposed to be looking for in your code sample). Could you add some type signatures (possibly tentative) of things you are looking for?

Comment: You should be able to do this by converting to boxed vectors first. If you need the raw performance of never leaving unboxed-land, you're probably going to need to patch the library yourself.

Comment: @Alec added the type signature of the function I'm looking for

Comment: @DanielWagner how would using boxed vectors allow me to do in comparison to unboxed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Monad m => (a -> m (Vector b)) -> Vector a -> m (Vector b)` is not too difficult - we can rely on the `Functor`, `Monad`, and `Traversable` instances of `Vector`. The big caveat is you will need to use a regular (not unboxed) `Vector`.

```
import Data.Vector (Vector)
import Control.Monad (join)

concatMapM :: Monad m => (a -> m (Vector b)) -> Vector a -> m (Vector b)
concatMapM f v = join <$> sequence (fmap f v)
```

The problem with doing this for unboxed vectors is that in the intermediate `fmap f v` step I have a `Vector (m (Vector b))` and there is no reasonable `data instance` for that (nor the required corresponding `Monad m => Vector Vector (m (Vector b))` class instance).

Comment: Pretend for a moment that the `mate` function was not monadic, e.g. it had type sig `(Int, Int) -> m (VU.Vector Int)` so that using `concatMap` was possible. Would the big-o runtime be different from your case, assuming boxed vectors in both cases?

Comment: @tsorn Do you mean `(Int, Int) -> (VU.Vector Int)`? Isn't `(Int, Int) -> m (VU.Vector Int)` the type it currently has?

Comment: Yes, sorry, that's what I meant

Comment: @tsorn Without optimizations, the asymptotic complexity would be the same. That said, the `vector` package is well-known for aggressively using rewrite rules and the non-monadic version would be more susceptible to this, so it could end up getting fused into something that is _much_ faster.

Comment: Very helpful answers. I can't find the runtime for concatMap or deduce it for your `concatMapM`. Would that be something like O(n+m) where n is input length and m is output length? Assuming `f` is constant.

Comment: @tsorn I think it is indeed O(n+m) for some fixed `f`.